# Good naming convention for scala "pimpers"

Tags: java, scala, adapter

I don't like the fact that in scala its not obvious what some of my imports are doing - imports for `implicits` so i'm trying to come up with good naming conventions for them so when i see in my `import` statements something like:

```
import com.mycomp.example.RectangleImplicits
```

or

```
import com.mycomp.example.RectanglePimper
```

I know i cant remove that import because its being used for `pimping`.

My problem with the above names is that sometimes I actually do an adapter, in that case

```
import com.mycomp.example.RectangleAdapter
```

does not say anyting about the fact that its actually a `pimper` however i don't want to name it `RectangleAdapterPimp` because the name becomes to combersome...

is there a `golden bullet` naming convention for that?

thanks

Comment: The term "enrich" is generally used in favor of "pimp" these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In std Scala library such classes are prefixed with `Rich`, like `RichString`, `RichInt`, etc... So why not to use `RichRectangleAdapter`

Comment: sounds good :) what if i adapt my rectangle for multiple systems with multiple `pimpers` which names would you suggest  like system one is in `meters` system, `RichRectangleMetersAdapter` which would allow me to do something like `rectangle.metersLength` isn't that too long cumbersome? in general i take a `class` and enrich it to be able to work with another system `API` using implicit conversions.

Comment: That depends on the case, if you have repeatable data, then it's ok and you can use some plugin to reduce boilerplate code.

Comment: not only Rich, but also Ops, e.g. [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps)

Comment: @om-nom-nom so if i have my internal `Alert` `case class` and I want to use some `System2` `alertSender` but `System2` `alertSender` requirs `someOtherAlertDTO` how would you recommend naming my converter?  `AlertOps` / `RichAlert` / `AlertSystem2Converter` / `AlertSystem2ConverterOps` / `RichAlertSystem2Converter` / `RichAlertConverter` ? what do you think? :)

Comment: @Jas Ops is used when you have to do something with Foo, but at the end of the day, return Foo, not the pimped wrapper class. Rich* is used for the later situation and in your case seems to be more suitable. If the only purpouse of such implicit class is to satisfy that method and not to add functionality to wrapped class, stick with Converter. See also so called [magnet pattern](http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/).